# ¿ Cómo mostrar las imagenes guardadas en Nodejs desde Angular?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express

Necesito mostrar la imagenes que estan guardads en `Nodejs/express` desde `Angular`. En `Nodejs/express` las imagenes estan guardadas en una carpeta **uploads** y en la base de datos `Postgresql` cada registro de libro tiene la ruta de su imagen correspondiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde `Angular` tengo un `servicio` donde obtiene la lista de todos los libros guardados en la base de datos y al recorrer esa lista con un `*ngFor` quiero mostrar la imagen de cada libro. Cuando recorro la lista, en `book.url_image` muestra la ruta asi: **uploads\7c76ce1e-9bce-46e1-9fb0-77dc3c0a82e7.jpg**
obviamente en la etiqueta `<img>` no muestra nada.

```html
<div *ngFor="let book of bookList$ | async">
    <p>{{book.url_image}}}</p>
    <img [src]="book.url_image">
</div>
```

Y ahí es donde estoy perdido, porque no se como hacer para mostrar las imagenes.

Aca en `Nodejs` mi `controller.ts` para obtener la lista de libros.

```js
export const getBooksWithAuthorName = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    try{
        const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('SELECT books.id_book, books.name, books.url_image, authors.name AS Autor FROM books INNER JOIN authors ON books.id_author = authors.id_author');
        return res.status(200).json(response.rows);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json('Internal server error');
    }    
}
```

Aca la ruta en mi archivo `routes.ts`

```js
router.get('/booksAuthorName', getBooksWithAuthorName);
```

En `Angular` el servicio `book.service.ts`

```js
 getBooksWithAuthorName() {
    return this.http.get<Book[]('http://localhost:4000/booksAuthorName');
  }
```

mi `component.ts` implementando el servicio

```js
bookList$: Observable<Book[]>;
  
constructor(public bookService: BookService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName();
}
```

y aca el `component.html`

```html
<div *ngFor="let book of bookList$ | async">
    <p>{{book.url_image}}</p>
    <img [src]="book.url_image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de esta forma:

**Desde Nodejs:**

1. Cree una carpeta **public** y adentro de la misma la carpeta **uploads**
2. A `Multer` tuve que indicarle que guarde las imagenes en la carpeta public/uploads.
3. En mi archivo `server.ts` declare `app.use(express.static('public'));` de esta forma puedo ver las imagenes en el servidor escribiendo en el navegador: `http://localhost:4000/uploads/cb27f405-1e09-4569-9589-f34be646ae46.jpg`

**Desde Angular:**

1. En la etiqueta  le vinculo una función donde recibe el **path** de la imagen de la base de datos, donde voy a necesitar hacerle unos cambios. Porque este **path** por defecto viene de la siguiente forma:
   `public\uploads\cb27f405-1e09-4569-9589-f34be646ae46.jpg` y esto trae 2 inconvenientes.

- uno de ellos es que el **path** lo muestra con barras invertidas `"\"` .
- y el otro inconveniente es el `"public"` al inicio del **path**.

Entonces si a mi etiqueta `<img>` le indico la ruta tal cual esta:
**http://localhost:4000/public\uploads\cb27f405-1e09-4569-9589-f34be646ae46.jpg** no va a mostrar nada.

Aca en mi `component.ts` la funcion

```js
linkImg(urlImage) {
    // quito la palabra public
    let str = urlImage.replace(/public/g, '');
    // quito la barra '\'
    str = str.replace('\\', '');
    // invierto la barra en sentido a '/'
    str = str.replace('\\', '/');
    // console.log(str);
    const URL = 'http://localhost:4000/';
    const link = URL + str;
    return link;
  }
```

y en mi `component.html`

```html
<div *ngFor="let book of bookList$ | async">
    <img [src]="linkImg(book.url_image)">
</div>
```